# Locate tab if opened among multiple tabs (chrome browser)

Tags: developer-console, redirect, chrome

**Scenario**: There are 10 tabs opened in chrome browser. In one of the tabs, I have developer console opened.

**Action**: In a new tab I try to open developer console under my **name**, beside **setup** (refer pic). But it redirects me to that tab where the developer console is already opened.

This can be seen only in Chrome browser and not in IE and Firefox. I guess this is Javascript in action.

How can I achieve this? Could anyone point me to the right direction.

I don't want to install any chrome extension.

Comment: Copy and paste the url and open in new tab ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is currently not possible in Chrome to open multiple copies of developer console for same org in multiple tabs.

It is possible for multiple orgs though but then you run into a problem where it's difficult to identify which dev console belongs to which org. There is an [open idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBXPAA2) for showing instance name in the Developer Console so you can identify which console belongs to which environment.